# Is there a go framework that only uses Protocol buffers to communicate with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, go, mapreduce, protocol-buffers

I was exploring options to write hadoop map/reduce programs in golang. I want to make use native hadoop apis using Hadoop RPC and not alternative solutions like streaming etc.

Comment: These can be a good start http://hortonworks.com/blog/go-hadoop-err-hadoop-and-go/ https://github.com/colinmarc/hdfs